# ipywidgets tab not displaying every time

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

In googleColab, I am creting 3 tabs using ipywidgets, and filling them with plots from Plotly.
However it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't display the first plot:

Here is the code, and a [link to github with COLAB](https://github.com/leodtprojectsd/Stack_questions/blob/main/Colab_ipywidget_not_working.ipynb) example i created.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()
fig0 = px.line(df.query("continent=='Africa'"), x="year", y="lifeExp", title='fig0')
fig1 = px.line(df.query("continent=='Oceania'"), x="year", y="lifeExp", title='fig1')
fig2= px.line(df.query("continent=='Europe'"), x="year", y="lifeExp", title='fig2')

figures = {"fig0": fig0, 
     "fig1": fig1, 
     "fig2": fig2}

sub_tab=[widgets.Output() for i in range(len(figures))]
tab = widgets.Tab(sub_tab)
for i, k in enumerate(figures):
    tab.set_title(i,k)
    with sub_tab[i]:
       figures[k].show()
display(tab)
```

Not working:
[image]

Working:
[image]

#TRIAL FROM r-beginners comment: sometimes wont show tab1
[image]

Comment: Is the version of Plotly you are currently using up-to-date? I will share [my results](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TjgnKYcNxKYD72646xKmkYyskcADPOl1?usp=sharing) obtained with the latest version of Plotly.

Comment: I've just ran your link and all requirements were satisfied. Your link also worked some times, and other times didn't (see edited question)